# customized adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working

Tags: android, adapter

i am using a customized adapter of list view to show an image and title.
In my application i add and remove the items in the list and i have to show that changes on the interface.
on any change in data i get all list from data base and store it in adapter list and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but interface is not showing any change.
on the other hand when i directly add or remove item from adapter it respond correctly.
i have used simple adapter and for that adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is working fine but for customized it is not responding.
i have also tried many solution on the stackoverflow but non of them work.
like
[Updating the list view when the adapter data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198425/updating-the-list-view-when-the-adapter-data-changes)

[Android List view refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088862/android-list-view-refresh/4088889#4088889)

[Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775255/adapter-notifydatasetchanged-is-not-working)

[notifyDataSetChange not working from custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422120/notifydatasetchange-not-working-from-custom-adapter)

i doing this as folows
at oncreate

```
enter code here

            product_data = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getInt("list_id");
    }
    product_data = db.getAllProductsstatus(value, 1);
    Collections.reverse(product_data);

    adapter = new ProductAdopter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, product_data, 2);
    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listView1);
```

and in onMenuItemSelected

```
enter code here
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

      int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
      String listItemName = adapter.getItem(info.position)._name;
      int id = adapter.getItem(info.position)._id;

         if(menuItemIndex == 0)
        {

            db.deleteProduct(adapter.getItem(info.position));

            product_data = db.getAllProducts(value);
            Collections.reverse(product_data);
            //adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(menuItemIndex == 1){
            String name ;
            if (adapter.getItem(info.position)._status == 0){
                popall("bar code", "no bar code entered");                  
            }
            else {
            popall("bar code", adapter.getItem(info.position)._bar_code);
            }
        }
        else if (menuItemIndex == 2){
            adapter.getItem(info.position)._status = 0;
            adapter.getItem(info.position)._bar_code = "0";
            db.updateProduct(adapter.getItem(info.position));
                product_data = db.getAllProductsstatus(value, 1);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            popall("alert", "successfully done");
        }
      return true;
}
```

my customized adapter class is given below

```
public class ProductAdopter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    List<Product> data = null;
    int source;
    public ProductAdopter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Product> product_data, int source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, layoutResourceId, product_data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = product_data;
        this.source = source;
    }
   // public ProductAdopter(MainActivity context2, int listviewItemRow, List<Product> product_data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ProductHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null && source == 1)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((MainActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ProductHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        if(row == null && source == 2)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((purchased)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ProductHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        if(row == null && source == 3)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Skiped)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ProductHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }


        else
        {
            holder = (ProductHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Product product = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(product.getName());
        if(product.icon.equals("no")){
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        }
        else{
            File imgFile = new  File(product.icon);
            if(imgFile.exists()){

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 70, 70, true);

                holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(resized); 
                myBitmap.recycle();
            }           
        }

        return row;
    }
    static class ProductHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah. That's the behaviour of ArrayAdapter<>: it does not track the original array you supplied. You'll have to add and delete objects in both your array and the adapter.

Comment: i know and that is the problem that i should not add item in both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that in your `onMenuItemSelected()` you have this line:

```
product_data = db.getAllProducts(value);
```

When you created the adapter in `onCreate()`, you gave it a reference to `product_data`. At that point your changes to `product_data` would propagate into the adapter, because it has a reference to your list.

But as soon as you assign a new list to your `product_data` variable (like you do in the `onMenuItemSelected()`) the adapter now has a reference to the old list, while your `product_data` now points to a new list. So your adapter doesn't know about your changes in the new list.

Instead of reassigning the variable, try clearing it and copying your items like this:

```
product_data.clear();
product_data.addAll(db.getAllProducts(value));
```

On another note, if you read your data from the database, you should consider using a `CursorAdapter` instead.

Here is a simple tutorial:
http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/

Comment: I have been looking into this for the pass few hours and couldn't figure it out. Truly awesome answer, truly awesome explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that, you are notifying your adapter
To refresh the list but you are not supplying fresh data
`(I.e after add/remove items.)` To it.

**Do as follow :**

```
    if(menuItemIndex == 0) { db.deleteProduct(adapter . Get item(info.position)); product_data = db.getAllProducts(value); 
    Collections.reverse(product_data);


    adapter = new ProductAdopter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, product_data, 2); ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

 //adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position)); 
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

}
```

Doing this you are supplying new data to adapter
So it will refresh list view to show fresh changed
data even without calling 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Also you need to make list view object as 
global in order to use it while 
Settimg new adapter in onMenuItemSelected ()

I hope this will solve your problem.